# Bit bucket repo Mirroring to Google Cloud Source Repositories

Tags: google-app-engine

I have been trying to aad a trigger for my gcp project while merging with master in my bitbucket repo. But the mirroring of my repo to google source repo is still loading after 2 days. Its showing repo is connected. Mirroring is in progress. Will show the content when process is completed. I tried with a sample repo with just readme file and it worked. But my actual repo is not mirroring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made a new repo in bitbucket and pushed without commit history. Repo was instantly mirrored after adding the trigger in google cloud platform. Trigger also working fine as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried forcing repository sync? You can take a look here [Forcing repository sync](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/mirroring-a-bitbucket-repository#forcing_repository_sync) to know more about it. You problem must be solved doing it.